# How to make a full screen modal using bootstrap-modal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap-sass v. 2.1 and bootstrap-modal-rails v. 2.1.1 in Rails but fail to create a full screen modal. For now I have a combi of a really tall modal and a wide modal based on the [demo](http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/), but I would like to get 100% width and 100% height. Is that possible?

```
#jbrowse-modal.modal.container.expand.hide.fade{"data-replace" => "true", :tabindex => "-1"}
  .modal-header
    %button.close{"aria-hidden" => "true", "data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"} &times;
    %h3
      = @scaffold.name
    .modal-body
      %div{:style => "height: 1000px; overflow: hidden;"}
        %iframe{:id => "jbrowse-iframe", :src => "/JBrowse/was_index.html?loc=ctgA", :style => "border: 1px solid black"}
```

Answer (score 3):

I tested this on an exising project. These simple rules should get you in the right direction:

```
#jbrowse-modal {
width: 100%;
left: 0;
margin-left: 0;
top: 0;
margin-top: 0!important;
height: 100%;
}
```

@tcgumus is on the right track.

Comment: Oh, excellent. I tried this and it is almost there (after removing the original height: 1000px style). The width is spot on, but the hight looks like its the modal-body that is 100% - it overflows with the hight of the modal-header.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should play with .modal class not .modal-body.
it has left: 50% ant top:20%. make default to your .modal-body and change .modal.

please use this code in modal

```
display: block;
width: 100% !important;
left: 0 !important;
margin: 0 !important;
height: 100% !important;
```

Comment: I combined the suggestions from the demo mentioned above. I tried to change the height to 100%, but that didn't do anything. Also changing CSS for .modal to 100% width and height don't do anything.

Comment: i changed it please check :)

Comment: Same-same. Width looks good. Height looks like modal-body is 100%. I havn't been touching .modal-body - only .modal

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3:

```
.modal-dialog {
  width: 98%;
  height: 98%;
  padding: 0;
}

.modal-content {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```